# Are questions about video cameras allowed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, allow, video

Am I allowed to ask about camcorders and other such video related tools? I am pretty sure questions about video technique are off-topic, but what about the actual cameras?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope.  They're off topic.  And there is http://avp.stackexchange.com for those questions.